# How to build a custom raster mosaic operator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic, operator

I'm trying to find a way to build a custom raster mosaic operator. When I Mosaic different raster to a new raster ArcMap lets u chose between "first", "last", "max" etc. I need a operator that chooses not the maximum cell value but the second highest cell value. F.e. if I add 3 overlapping rasters, which contain values from 1 to 3, I want the resulting raster to be 2 instead of 3 (max) in the overlapping area. I thought this would be easily doable with a map algebra expression in the raster calculator, but can't make it work. 
So I was thinking a python tool, but I can't seem to get a good start. I checked out rastertonumpyarry and this might even work. But since the raster to new mosaic tool is already almost doing what I want (except for the "second highest cell value operator") I was hoping to find an easier way.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [Combine](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm) to collect all raster values into a single table:

[image]

2. Calculate the second highest value into a new column, using Field Calculator Python expression like: `sorted([ !att1! , !att2! , !att3! , !att4! ])[-2]`
3. Use [Lookup](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/lookup.htm) tool to make new raster, using the calculated value from step 2.

Comment: tank you for your answer, but how am I supposed to get the values into a table? Combine produces a raster which a.f.a.i.k. has no attribute table.

Comment: It creates an integer raster, which does have an attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to thank you again for your answer, phloem...this is a very nice and easy way to do it. Because of restrictions to the tool (only int and max number of rasters) I wound up converting my rasters to points a doing automated spatial joins, but still